# Iterative Datetime - TypeError: an integer is required

Tags: python, datetime

I wish to create a series of epoch time stamps from a datetime object.

I can do this with one datetime like so:

```
start_time = calendar.timegm(datetime.datetime(2015,9,30,0).timetuple())
```

returning:

`1443571200`

I wish to iterate over a list of datetimes to create a series of epoch time stamps.

```
slices = [(2015,9,30,0),(2015,10,04,23)]

for time_slice in slices:
    start_time = calendar.timegm(datetime.datetime(time_slice).timetuple())
```

However, this returns a `TypeError: an integer is required`

How do I iteratively use the `calendar` and `datetime` modules to create epoch time stamps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following *list comprehension*. Simply unpack the item and pass it to the `datetime` constructor:

```
>>> from calendar import timegm
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> start_times  = [timegm(datetime(*slc).timetuple()) for slc in slices] 
>>> start_times
[1443571200, 1443999600]
```